# One way, fast, no-caching, XML-cursor/enumerator/reader-like parser in Haskell?

Tags: xml, haskell

So I need to read a large XML file. I don't want to parse it to a DOM tree and keep it all in memory. What I am rather looking for is a reader that provides fast, noncached, forward-only access to XML data in Haskell.

**EDIT:** There are a few question seemingly on the same subject, however I didn't find the answer there. So what I am looking for again is:

1. An XML-cursor (fast, one-way, no laziness, no caching, process as you go style) lib
2. An example how to use it.

**EDIT:** Text.XML.Enumerator.Parse seems to be [the answer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-enumerator-0.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Enumerator-Parse.html): 
Is this a good choice?

Answer (score 2):

The best module I've used for a similar task is [Text.XML.Stream.Parse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.1.0.7/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html) from the [xml-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit) package. The module index contains this simple example of the API:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Data.Conduit (($$))
import Data.Text (Text, unpack)
import Text.XML.Stream.Parse

data Person = Person Int Text
    deriving Show

parsePerson = tagName "person" (requireAttr "age") $ \age -> do
    name <- content
    return $ Person (read $ unpack age) name

parsePeople = tagNoAttr "people" $ many parsePerson

main = do
    people <- runResourceT $
            parseFile def "people.xml" $$ force "people required" parsePeople
    print people
```